Triggering endpoints during navigation within WhatsApp Business Flows - how?
Issue
Inside the WhatsApp Flows I found several places where they say that it's possibile to call data_exchange to call your endpoint and reply with the next screen you want to navigate to.
For example here, you can find:

For any navigation between two screens, you could use the data_exchange action to call the endpoint. The endpoint will then return the next screen and its input data.

Or here:

You want to submit the data from screen to your server and transition to the next screen.

It's great to hear we can do that, but how? I cannot find a way to actually tell the flow to navigate to the next screen.
I tried to use this code generated by an ai but it doesn't work, since it only calls the current screen (BOOK_APPOINTMENT) again.
   {
      version: '3.1',
      screen: 'BOOK_APPOINTMENT',
      action: 'navigate',
      next_screen: 'REGISTER',
      data: {
        date: '24, Saturday, 2024',
        time_slot: '10.00',
      },
    }

Do you know how to achieve this? Is there additional documentation I should be aware of?

Eureka! I figured it out. Turns out I was overlooking a crucial detail in the Facebook Developers documentation here. The response code is:
{
    "version": "<VERSION>",
    "screen": "<SCREEN_NAME>", // -> Use the name of your next screen
    "data": {
      "property_1": "value_1",
       ...
      "property_n": "value_n",
      "error_message": "<ERROR-MESSAGE>"
    }
}

which in my case is:
{
  version: '3.1',
  screen: 'REGISTER',
  data: {
    date: '24, Saturday, 2024',
    time_slot: '10.00',
  },
}

